# In Python, How do you prevent partial matches using re.search if you are using a dictionary key as your pattern

Tags: python

How do you prevent parital matches while using re.search if you are using a dictionary key as your pattern in Python.  For this question I would like to avoid iterating through the nested list in the dictionary value.  I've tried appending regular expressions to the search pattern but it results in error.

Partial Match:

```
>>> d
{'server': '192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.22, 192.168.1.2'}

>>> e
'192.168.1'

>>> match = re.search(e, d['server'])

>>> if match:
...   print match.group()
...
192.168.1
```

Comment: `d['server']` is an expression that means, "assuming `d` is a dictionary, look up the value associated with the key `server`.  It shouldn't matter that a dictionary value is your target string; any string is scannable with a regular expression. (It isn't your pattern.  '192.168.1' is your pattern and it isn't escaped properly.)  (Whether thet pattern makes sense or not is a different issue.) The question isn't clear; what are you hoping to see for output?

Comment: as you can see in the example a partial match occurs on a substring, adding regular expression to the endo fo the variable 'e' generates errors.  Do you know a means to combine the variable with a regex to prevent partial matches?

Comment: -1 The question makes no sense. Using a dictionary in no way changes how its string values are matched with regex. And where the heck do you have a "nested list"? You have a string as your value. Clarify your question.

Comment: "Do you know a means to combine the variable with a regex to prevent partial matches?" What does this even mean? How does one "combine  a variable with a regex"?

Comment: What in the world can you possibly be calling a partial match? I see a complete match.  Three of them, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re only trying to match an IPv4 address, you can use the regex `192\.168\.1\.\d+`.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '192.168.1.2, 192.168.11.9, 192.168.1.255, 10.14.1.1'
>>> regex = '192\.168\.1\.\d+'
>>> re.search(regex, text).group()
'192.168.1.2'
>>> re.findall(regex, text)
['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.255']
```

Comment: You need to use either double backslashes (`192\\.168\\.1\\.\d+`) or raw strings (r'192\.168\.1\.\d+') for Python's sake.  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: Ah, true, I forgot that.
But, it seems to work? `repr('\.') => '\\.'`

Comment: Try the same using a variable  against a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression pattern, a `.` without a `\` (well, a `\\` for Python) in front of it is a special character which matches any one character.  Are you looking for IP addresses that start with your pattern?  For that use `192\\.168\\.1\\.\d+` or some variant.  Alternatively, if you can get each of those IPs into a string by itself then you can use:

```
if ip.startswith(e):
  # etc.
```